# SQL 2005 AD Group permission levels

Tags: active-directory, permissions, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to give permissions to a (sql 2005) database app based on AD groups.  The general idea is to require a user to have a membership to "app_users" to view anything, and membership to other groups gives them write access to that group.  "app_customers" gives write access to the customers module, "app_sales" to sales, etc.

I've listed an example below:

user1: AD member of app_users
user2: AD member of app_users, app_customers

For dbo.customers table:
app_users
- Granted: Select permission
- Denied: Insert, Update, Delete

app_customers
- Granted: Select permission
- Granted: Insert, Update, Delete

I would expect user1 to be able to view the dbo.customers table, but will not be allowed to modify anything (insert/update/delete) - which works.  In the same vein, I would expect user2 to be able to view AND modify the dbo.customers table, since they are a member of app_customers.

However, this is not the case.  Instead, user2 is denied any modifications just like user1.  I seem to remember something about deny permissions winning if there was a conflict, but it's honestly been too long since I've dealt with them.

Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deny will always override grant.  You need to revoke the DENY right to app_users.  If the user doesn't have rights you don't need to DENY rights unless you never want them to have rights to the table.

```
select sys.schemas.name 'Schema', sys.objects.name Object, sys.database_principals.name username, sys.database_permissions.type permissions_type,
    sys.database_permissions.permission_name,
    sys.database_permissions.state permission_state,
    sys.database_permissions.state_desc,
    state_desc + ' ' + permission_name + ' on ['+ sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name + '] to [' + sys.database_principals.name + ']' COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS
from sys.database_permissions
join sys.objects on sys.database_permissions.major_id =
    sys.objects.object_id
join sys.schemas on sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
join sys.database_principals on sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id =
    sys.database_principals.principal_id
order by 1, 2, 3, 5
```

Comment: I remembered Deny overriding everything, but I'm still not getting the desired behavior.  My user2 still cannot make updates to the dbo.customers table, even thought they are a member of app_customers.  I'm expecting SQL Server to aggregate the AD Groups, but it doesn't appear to be working.  Am I going about this the wrong way?  I'm wondering if I should be using roles instead?

Comment: Can you run the code above and post the results?

Comment: I figured it out.  I was running these tests by setting the permissions directly against the AD groups in sql server.  As soon as I created roles (with those permissions) and mapped them to the ad groups I started getting the behavior I desired:  anyone in group app_customers now has access to dbo.customers, and anyone not in that group does not.